# How does index*int in a for loop end up with zero as result?

Tags: java, for-loop, int

We tried just for fun to create a for loop like below. We assumed that the number we get would be very high but we got 0. Why is it 0 and not something big? 
We even tried it with a long because we thought it might be bigger than a int.
Thanks in advance.

```
private static void calculate() {
    int currentSolution = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        currentSolution *= i;
    }
    System.out.println(currentSolution);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `int` is wrapping round to `-2147483648` when it reaches `+2147483647`.

By an amazing coincidence<sup>1</sup>, a multiplication by zero is introduced into your product.

See for yourself: write

```
if (currentSolution == 0){
    // What is the value of i?
}
```

You'll need a `BigInteger` to evaluate 100!.

---

<sup>1</sup> Really it's not that amazing: it's just that 100! has 2<sup>32</sup> as a factor.

Comment: This happens when `i` reaches 34. `currentSolution` becomes and stays 0.

Comment: when value of i is 32 and 33 the currentSolution is having the same value, why is that

Comment: Just do the multiplication by hand subject to the `int` overflow rule in Java, and you'll see (assuming of course what you way is true).

Comment: Its not an amazing coincidence, the value lf `currentSolution` is exceeding the range of an `int`.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran 32! and 33! are the same value for the same reason 34! is 0 (at least with `int` data type): It overflows, and just in "funny" ways. If you use BigInteger, you can try it: 34! divided by 2^32 has a remainder of 0, and 32! and 33! just share the same remainder when dividing by 2^32.

Answer (score 0):

Your datatypes are too small, even if you use long, so you cannot do this calculation with basic types. So you get an overflow, where the values become negative, and at some point 0. Therefore, the result is still zero after every loop.

You can see that by printing the `currentSolution` in the loop.

In order to get the correct solution, try using `BigInteger`:

```
public static void calculate() {
    BigInteger currentSolution = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        currentSolution = currentSolution.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println(currentSolution);
}
```

This outputs the correct solution: 933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214685929638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979208272237582511852109168640000000000000000000000

Comment: As the icing on the cake, you could mention that this very long number modulo 4294967296 is zero, which accounts for the result the OP gets.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop calculates the factorial of 100, i.e. 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * 99 * 100, also written as 100! which equals 9.332621544×10157

The range of int is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and the range of long is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, so with a number that is 10157 you've hit multiplication overflow long before you even get close to the end of the for loop.

The overflow eventually results in all bits eventually zeroing out, thus producing the result 0.

Answer (score -3):

You re basically calculating 100!, which is approximately 9.3e+157, whereas a long maximum value is 2^64 -1 so approximately 1.8e+19.

It cant fit, thats why you have 0.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. If a value doesn't fit an `int` or `long` it isn't set to 0. It overflows.

Comment: Well, when I do : `int i = 429496729;
         i = i*100;
          System.out.println(i);` I get -60, and not an overflow.

Comment: yes, you get -60 instead of 42949672900 because the `int` overflows. It meanse that the maximum integer + 1 results in the minimum integer. But not 0.

Comment: Actually, yes, if you increase the value a significant amount of time, you end up getting 0. `i = i*100*100*100*100*100*100*100*100*100*100*100*100*100*100000000;` i is giving me 0.

Comment: acctually you only get 0 by coincedence. E.g. in a case like `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 + Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: change all the `100` to `101` in your example. Should be an even bigger number, right? By your argumentation, the result should still be `0` but it's acctually `-1804217088`.